# Is it possible to separate script part of the vue single file component into multiple js files

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I built my project with the Vue CLI. I am not expert with vue, still learning. So I need help because I can not solve one problem.
First I wanted to separate script part of the SFC which I menaged to do.
In SvgMap.vue component I wrote:

```
<script src="../js/SvgMap.js"></script>
```

and my code in separate file SvgMap.js is working fine.

The problem is when I want to separate my code in SvgMap.js in different javascript files. I dont know how to include them all in the vue component. Is this actually possible?

In my project I use javascript to generate a lot of data from svg map component (coordinates, text, colors...) which I want to be in separate files. The data will be leter used in other component from vuex library.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do, is to split up your code into different files.

From these files, you'll need to [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) the parts that you need in your `SvgMap.js`.

In your `SvgMap.js` you just need to [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) the exports and you're good to go.

Here is an example:
`export.js`

```js
export function addNumbers(a,b){
    return a+b
}
```

`main.js`

```js
import { addNumbers } from './path/to/export.js'

console.log(addNumbers(1,2))
```